# C detect user typing characters in stdin

Tags: c, idle-timer

Is it possible to detect whether a user is simply *typing* anything into stdin?

`man select` says:

> select() and  pselect()  allow  a  program  to  monitor  multiple  file
>          descriptors,  waiting  until one or more of the file descriptors become
>          "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).

I guess "ready" means EOF or NL. But what about single characters? Could you program a timer-callback in C, which starts when the user has been idle for some seconds? If yes, how?

Comment: Well, yes,and no, you'd need to actually read the console using the *raw mode*

Comment: In this context "ready" means that a `read()` or `write()` operation on the file descriptor wouldn't block. On the other hand, what you are trying to do won't work like this, because by default the standard input is buffered, so that the user can edit the input line. You want to set the terminal on "raw" mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you have to put your terminal into *character* mode. By default, programs usually start in *line* mode, where your program doesn't get notified for input until a whole line was entered.

You should use a library like for example **ncurses** to put your terminal into character mode, for example with

```
initscr();
cbreak();
```

Now, if you `select()` your standard input, you will be notified for each character entered, which you can retrieve with `getch()`.

For more details, the [NCURSES Programming HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) might help.

Edit on request of the OP:

If you just have to support linux, you would set the appropriate options in the terminal configuration.

First, read in the current parameters:

```
struct termios config;
tcgetattr(0, &config);
```

Then, switch canonical (line mode) off:

```
config.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
```

and specify, that a single character suffices to return from read:

```
config.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
```

Finally, set these parameters on your stdin terminal:

```
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &config);
```

Now, a `read()` should return on a single character read.

Comment: Why do you recommend using a library? Would a proper solution be too difficult?

Comment: Not too difficult, but tedious if you want to be portable; There are potentially many environments to support, if you use ncurses, you support many of them and the code is easy. If you want to do it by hand, you have much more code and only support one single environment.

Comment: Let's say I just have to support Linux. How could I do this?

Comment: @user1511417 I explained it in the answer above

Comment: I've tried this! It works!! Thank you.
*Note*: You have to `#include <termios.h>`.